# how to use defineCollisionRectangle?

Tags: java, java-me, midp, lcdui

For starters, how can I use [defineCollisionRectangle API](http://docs.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/javax/microedition/lcdui/game/Sprite.html#defineCollisionRectangle%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29)?

I've done some research about it and I think it doesn't have any use at all.

True that I can just use `collidesWith()` to check if 2 sprites collide.

But what I want to use a sprite that has parameters like house with a backyard fence around it.

I tried using the `defineCollisionRectangle()` in a condition, set it in the constructor but I don't know how to use it.

I can just use `object.getX/gety` and `object.getWidth/getHeight`, to make a Parameter around the sprite.

What does  `defineCollisionRectangle` really do and how do I use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To detect collision for objects like `house` with a `fence` around it I would start with defining **two Sprite** objects - one for fence, another for house - each with its **own** collision rectangle.

To render a house with fence around it, I'd draw *houseSprite* over *fenceSprite* like at the sketch below:

> [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Wn5B.jpg]

With this approach it would be really easy to tell whether collision happened with fence or with house - simply because each defines its own collision rectangle.

---

Generally, when you find out that single collision rectangle doesn't do what you need, you invent a way to decompose things to more rectangular sub-elements so that when combined, these elements simulate / approximate desired behavior.

- *End users* just don't care how many Sprite objects are there behind the scene. They're happy as long as end result feels about like *house with a backyard fence around it*.